# How to induct for double summation?

Tags: summation, induction

I have no idea on how to approach this?

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_i + a_j = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_j  (it \space may \space be  \space wrong  \space it  \space is   \space just  \space an  \space example)
$$

Any hint on induction?

I think the base case is showing n+m = 2

then the induction hypothesis is some thing like this?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^{m+1}a_i + a_j  = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} a_j
$$

Comment: In general show that $(m,n)=(1,1)$ or $(0,0)$ is true, then assume $(m,n)$ to be true and show that both $(m+1,n)$ and $(m,n+1)$ are true. (Also your specific statement is false.)

Comment: Do you mean to show both of this?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m+1}a_i + a_j  = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{m+1} a_j
$$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_i + a_j  = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_j
$$

Comment: Yes, that is what you should do.